java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.apache.wink.common.internal.ResponseImpl$ResponseBuilderImpl does not define or inherit
When I reach this non-test code from a new unit test
Response.status(responseStatus).entity(response).build();

I am getting the following exception from a newly written unit test:
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.apache.wink.common.internal.ResponseImpl$ResponseBuilderImpl does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder status(int, java.lang.String)' of abstract class javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder.
    at javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder.status(Response.java:921)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status(Response.java:592)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status(Response.java:603)
    at c.i.c.riker.services.v3.resource.VendorWorkOrderV3Resource.rtsWorkOrderCreateMultipart(VendorWorkOrderV3Resource.java:947)
    at c.i.c.riker.services.v3.resource.VendorWorkOrderV3ResourceUnitTest.testRtsWorkOrderCreateMultipart(VendorWorkOrderV3UnitTest.java:134)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ...
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)

Before creating the unit test, I have not seen this exception happen.
Not that Response is javax.ws.rs.core.Response and ResponseBuilder is javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder, response is a String and responseStatus is javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status
Am using maven, and well as Mockito and JUnit 5 and Open Liberty server.
I am not sure how to proceed or what to try.
I am expecting no exception to happen when I call this.
pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
<url>https://raw.github.com/WASdev/ci.maven.tools/master/LICENSE</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.ibm.cio.riker</groupId>
    <artifactId>riker</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <relativePath>../</relativePath>
  </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>riker-services</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>rikerServices</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.wasdev.maven.tools.targets</groupId>
            <artifactId>liberty-target</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.cio.riker</groupId>
            <artifactId>riker-timer</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>microprofile-openapi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
<!-- newly added dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.cio.riker</groupId>
            <artifactId>riker-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>test-jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

   <build>
      <finalName>riker-services</finalName>
      <plugins>
          
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
               <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>copy-package-config</id>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <outputDirectory>../src/main/liberty/config</outputDirectory>
                     <resources>
                        <resource>
                           <directory>src/main/liberty/config</directory>
                        </resource>
                     </resources>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
               <execution>
                  <id>copy-package-war</id>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <outputDirectory>../target</outputDirectory>
                     <resources>
                        <resource>
                           <directory>./target</directory>
                           <includes>
                              <include>riker-services.war</include>
                           </includes>
                        </resource>
                     </resources>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
               <systemPropertyVariables>
                  <http.port>${liberty.var.default.http.port}</http.port>
                  <context.root>${liberty.var.default.contextroot}</context.root>
               </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <target>2.2</target>
                <sourceDestDir>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                <wsdlDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                <wsdlLocation>/wsdl/wfoutbound.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                <executable>${env.WAS_HOME}/bin/jaxws/wsimport</executable>
                <packageName>com.ibm.cio.riker.dao.wsdl</packageName>
                <keep>true</keep>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxws-tools</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.5</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>



ResponseBuilder.status(int, String) was added in JAX-RS 2.1.  In Liberty, Apache Wink is used for the JAX-RS 1.1 implementation.  So it would appear there is a mismatch between the API level you are testing with (2.1) and the implementation used (1.1).  If you want to test with JAX-RS 2.1, you will need to switch to the jaxrs-2.1 feature in your server.xml, otherwise you will need to use the 1.1 API for your JUnit / Mockito testing.
To give additional details, you would look at your src/main/liberty/config directory to look at how your Liberty server is configure.  Otherwise it would be good to know what your application (I believe it is riker-services.war) is using for Java EE levels.  You would want to have those sync'ed up to have the EE levels match between the two.
I hope that helps.
Jared Anderson
Update:
The problem ended up being that the sever.xml was using jaxrs-2.1 in it and with:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.wasdev.maven.tools.targets</groupId>
            <artifactId>liberty-target</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

Apache Wink is getting added.  That dependency is EE 6 based and should not be used with Jakarta EE 8 features.

Thanks for the help @Jared Anderson.
You are correct. I will bring it up to the person who worked on the application to see whether this dependency can be replaced with something compliant with Jakarta EE 8. If you happen to know, I am all ears!
For now, I added the following exclusion in that dependency to get things working for me:


org.apache.wink
wink-common

and adding jersey-common and jersey-client
